# $.ajax call not working in loop

Tags: ajax, jquery

hye i have an ajax call which is not working and i don't know why

my ajax call is

```
function insertData(icompany,iproduct,iavailability,irelatedInformation,ishortageReason,idateUpdated)
    {
        alert('here')//comes here just once but i have a loop which calls insertData function 
        $.ajax({
            url: '../includes/drugShortage.php',
            data: {
                   action:'insert' ,
                   company: '\'' + icompany +'\'',
                   product: '\'' + iproduct+'\'',
                   availability: '\'' + iavailability+'\'',
                   relatedInformation: '\'' + irelatedInformation+'\'',
                   shortageReason: '\'' + ishortageReason+'\'',
                   dateUpdated: '\'' + idateUpdated+'\''

            },
            success: function(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            },
            error:function(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            },
            type:GET
        });
    }
```

i don't know what is causing this.

Comment: You are not looping ,So it is not looping.

Comment: alert('here'); ? And where is the loop?

Comment: what does your console say? and how does `drugShortage.php` look like?

Comment: looping in each statement which i have not mentioned here

Comment: I am no expert in JQuery but doesn't it require an event trigger?When does the function should start?If it's on document load the function should start with $(document).ready(function(){ //the body of the function }); Please tell me when your function should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use setTimeout to call function periodically! I hopw this code will give you some hint for your assignment!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            insertData("", "", "", "", "", ""); //Pass Data Here...!!!
        }, 1000); //Call every 1 min
    });

    function insertData(icompany, iproduct, iavailability, irelatedInformation, ishortageReason, idateUpdated) {        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET"
            url: "../includes/drugShortage.php",
            data: {
                action: "insert",
                company: icompany,
                product: iproduct,
                availability: iavailability,
                relatedInformation: irelatedInformation,
                shortageReason: ishortageReason,
                dateUpdated: idateUpdated
            },
            success: function(event) {
                //TODO
            },
            error: function(e) {
                //TODO
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for `"type"` attribute should be quoted. Additionally, there is no need to specify the type for `jQuery ajax` call. The default value is `"GET"`. Also I will recommend you to turn on error reporting for Javascript in the browser and check console for script errors. It will help you a lot.

Comment: can you please also tell me whether i am passing the data values in right format i-e with in quoted strings

Comment: Data is PlainObject or String! In your case, you are passing as PlainObject. You don't need to escape local variable. Take a look at the code snippet I posted!